403 Error deploying a Container in an Azure Storage Account using Terraform
I have seen a lot of question on this topic in the forum but none of them seem to be solved properly.
I'm trying to deploy a Storage Account using Terraform, and in that SA I want to create a Container. When I deploy it, I get the following error:
Error: containers.Client#GetProperties: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailure" Message="This request is not authorized to perform this operation.\nRequestId:51828c6f-d01e-0037-297b-b2f7b5000000\nTime:2024-05-30T10:25:34.2404478Z"
│ 
│   with module.global.module.stxxst01xxenv-containers.azurerm_storage_container.main["custom_container_name"],
│   on ../../modules/storage-account/storage-container/main.tf line 4, in resource "azurerm_storage_container" "main":
│    4: resource "azurerm_storage_container" "main" {

The service principal I'm using has Contributor and Storage Blob Data Contributor in the Subscription, which should be enough.
However, if I execute a terraform apply again, this second time it is able to create the container.
My suspicion is that when it tries to create the container, the SA is not finished or something like that. Here is the .tf file I'm using:
# Create the RG
module "rg-da-stmain-xxxx-env" {
  source              = "../modules/resource-group"
  resource_group_name = "rg-da-stmain-xxxx-${var.environment}"
  location            = "West Europe"
  tags = {
    application = "x"
    created-by  = "x"
    deployer    = "x"
    stage       = var.environment
    team        = "x"
  }
}

# Create the Storage Account
module "stxxst01xxenv" {
  source                           = "../modules/storage-account"
  resource_group_name              = module.rg-da-stmain-xxxx-env.resource_group_name
  location                         = module.rg-da-stmain-xxxx-env.resource_group_location
  storage_account_name             = "stxxst01xx${var.environment}"
  storage_account_replication_type = "RAGRS"
  storage_account_tier             = "Standard"
  public_network_access_enabled    = false
  tags = {
    application = "x"
    created-by  = "x"
    deployer    = "x"
    stage       = var.environment
    team        = "x"
  }
  depends_on = [module.rg-da-stmain-xxxx-env]
}

# Create the Containers
module "stxxst01xxenv-containers" {
  source                = "../modules/storage-account/storage-container"
  storage_account_name  = module.stxxst01xxenv.storage_account_name
  container_access_type = "private"
  storage_containers    = ["custom_container_name"]
  depends_on            = [module.stxxst01xxenv]
}

Does anybody has an idea of what is happening? Thanks in advance.
P.S. If you need some more code let me know in the comments.

Please try changing the access level to container level as your providing "private" and also check with network configuration of storage account. Try again also please share the SS of SA configuration from portal @Rorepio

This issue can also mitigated by adding a delay or a retry mechanism between the creation of the storage account and the creation of the container.
Use
resource "time_sleep" "wait_30_seconds" {
depends_on = [null_resource.previous]
create_duration = "30s"
}
refer : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/time/latest/docs/resources/sleep

I have tried adding the time_sleep and still face the same error. Also, in order to be align with the company standards, the container has to be private...

Something interesting I found: https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/21805143295379-AzureRM-Service-returned-error-StatusCode-403-ErrorCode-AuthorizationFailure-When-Public-Network-Access-Disabled

I am not sure if it's the best solution and, to be honest, I don't really understand the reason but I was able to make it work with an easy fix: I was deploying 3 private endpoints in the same template, so what I did was include them in the container's depends on. That way, Terraform creates a resource group, then a storage account, the all 3 peps and, finally, the container.
